# Show only large icon when notification pulled in android

Tags: android, notifications

In my application i need to show the notification using native android api.
I am showing the notification by settings small and large icons.In recent OS devices (from 4.4) application is showing both small and large icons .

is there anyway to hide small icon when user pull notification and only show the large icon.

I have searched for the answers,but did not find working solution.

Below is the code i am using .

```
`Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                         .setContentTitle("Title")
                         .setContentText("Content")
                         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
                         .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.pull_down_icon);
                         .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
                        Notification mNotif = builder.build();
                    mNotificationManager.notify(SIMPLE_NOTFICATION_ID, mNotif);`
```

below is my observations.
 - when i set only small icon, then small icon is displayed for notification bar and when user pull the notification same icon is displayed.
 - when i set both (small and large) notification shown the small icon but, when user pull it shows both small and large

Comment: can you show your relevant code?

Comment: usually, if you just set the small icon, it will be shown bigger.....so try to set only small one and don´t set the large one...the small one is an obligation..

Comment: Edited the question with the code